# Generalized function to merge different number of dictionaries with different keys in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, nested

I want to make a generalized function to merge different number of nested dictionaries with different keys in nested dictionaries in python. However, this below function works fine if we have same keys within nested dictioanries:

```
data = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

result = {k: {ik: [] for ik in dict1[k].keys()} for k in dict1.keys()}

for entry in data:
  for key, value in entry.items():
    for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
        result[key][inner_key].append(inner_value)
```

My input dictionaries are:

```
dict1 = {"canada":{'america':189,'asia':175,'europe': 186},
     "norway":{'australia': 123,'africa':124,'brazil':125}}
dict2=  {"canada":{'florida':13,'asia':14,'europe': 15},
     "norway":{'california': 17,'africa':18,'brazil':19}}
dict3=  {"canada":{'africa':127,'asia':256,'europe': 16, 'brazil':15},
     "norway":{'australia': 17,'africa':18,'brazil':19}}
# Expected Output
{'canada': {'africa': 127,
'america': 189,
'asia': [175, 14, 256],
'brazil': 15,
'europe': [186, 15, 16],
'florida': 13},
'norway': {'africa': [124, 18, 18],
'australia': 123,
'brazil': [125, 19, 19],
'california': 17}}
```

Comment: are the outer keys the same across the dicts?

Comment: Yes outer are same but inner nested keys are not same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `dict.setdefault` for updating the inner dictionary.

```
out = {}
for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys() | dict3.keys():
    inner = {}
    for d in [dict1, dict2, dict3]:
        for i,j in d.get(k, {}).items():
            inner.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
    out[k] = inner
```

If the other keys are the same across the dictionaries, we could simplify it a bit.

Also if you insist on having ints (instead of lists) for singleton lists, you could try the following (but I don't think it's a good idea to mix data types since afterwards you'll need to check if the value is int or list):

```
def merge_dicts(dicts):
    out = {}
    for k in dicts[0]:
        inner = {}
        for d in dicts:
            for i,j in d.get(k, {}).items():
                if i in inner and isinstance(inner[i], list):
                    inner[i].append(j)
                elif i in inner:
                    inner[i] = [inner[i], j]
                else:
                    inner[i] = j
        out[k] = inner
    return out
```

Output:

```
>>> out = merge_dicts([dict1,dict2,dict3])
{'canada': {'america': 189,
  'asia': [175, 14, 256],
  'europe': [186, 15, 16],
  'florida': 13,
  'africa': 127,
  'brazil': 15},
 'norway': {'australia': [123, 17],
  'africa': [124, 18, 18],
  'brazil': [125, 19, 19],
  'california': 17}}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make a generalized function which we could use for any number of nested dictionaries using kwargs?

Comment: Basically, I want to make a generalized function for the above code which I could use for any number of nested dictionaries and could perform the same functionality as performed in your solution.